# Android ListView Memory Leak?

Tags: android, listview, memory-management, android-listview, drawable

I've implemented a sectioned list view so that every section has an adapter using [this guide](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) and probably it causes the views to be allocated over and over again when scrolling and not to reuse because there are different adapters (but when scrolling back, it reuses but for the same adapter) and it's getView method is like that (simplified):

```
        Map< String, ? > object = null;
        String id = null, title = null, rating = null, pic_url = null;
        object = sectionContent.get(position).getMap();
        id = (String) object.get(EventRowValues.ROW_ID);
        title = (String) object.get(EventRowValues.ROW_TITLE);
        pic_url = (String) object.get(EventRowValues.ROW_PIC_URL);

        View hView = convertView;
        if ( hView == null ) {
            hView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.popularity_row, null);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.pic = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.title = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            hView.setTag(holder);
        }

        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) hView.getTag();

        holder.id = id;

        mImageWorker.loadImage(pic_url, holder.pic);

        holder.title.setText(title);

        return hView;
```

The loadImage method is from [this google example](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html).

The problem is that when I scroll it takes more and more memory, for example 2 MB for 5-10 rows. When I scroll back it doesn't take any more memory but as far as I know it shouldn't allocate such amounts of memory because it reuses the views as I expect it to take memory just when it loads and when I scroll to use the same views and bitmaps from the cache (because much of the drawables are the same object returned from the cache).

What's might be the problem?
Any other option to smarter reusable sectioned listView?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So does your problem got solved by my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out,
I was using a sectioned table view from the guide I've mentioned before and it won't reuses the cells properly. I've implemented an ExpandableListView with some patches to make it work and now it's great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: **UPDATE:**

```
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if ( convertView == null ) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            hView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.popularity_row, null);
            holder.pic = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.title = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            hView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
```

PS: You have created holder object twice. Is it really needed?

Which android version are you using, coz I also had the same problem, I was using version 11, and on higher version, if you want to be able to scroll list quickly, you need to give `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` attribute in `activity tag` in manifest file.

Comment: Thanks but what's the difference between this code and mine? You're allocation the holder even in cases it's not needed. And do you mean to API level? And what does android:hardwareAccelerated does? Thanks

Comment: Please see my updated code. Here I have created only one holder object and using it in subsequent calls. There is a difference between creating an object an assigning value to it. Here, I have created object only for the first time, and assigned value to it for the subsequent calls. For HardwareAcceleration please read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question after finding interesting insights.

Answer (score 1):

comment out the mImageWorker.loadImage(pic_url, holder.pic); and show difference in memory consumption

Comment: It's the same consumption. 7MB for scrolling the list (30 items). Probably the allocation view itself and it's imageViews is responsible for this consumption and maybe the cells cells are being allocated and not reused (but when I scroll back it's still 7MB).

Comment: I've removed the imageViews from the xml and the code that corresponds to this views and now it takes 3MB for this list... still too much...

Comment: and does it still load up to 2 mb for every new 10 rows?